# Iterating combination of list, dict, etc. to call function recursively

Tags: python, eval, abstract-syntax-tree, python-itertools

I am given a function defined below:

```
def func(dframe, string1, str2, timedel1, bool1, dict1, dict2):
    ...
```

I want to call this function iteratively with following inputs:

```
dframe          = dframe
string1         = 'Cars'
str2_list       = ['Mercedes', 'BMW', ...]
timedelArg_list = ['seconds=1', 'seconds=2', 'mintues=2', ...]
bool1           = False
dict1_list      = [['Mercedes_color': 'black'], 
                   ['BMW_color': 'white']]
dict2_list      = ['Mercedes_price', 'BMW_price', ...]
```

I have control over how these inputs are organized but do not have control over `func`.

Each `func` call looks as follows:

```
# First Call
dframe = func(dframe, string1, str2_list[0], 
              timedelta(timedelArg_list [0]), 
              bool1 = bool1, 
              dict1 = {'FIXED1':dict1_list[0][0], 'FIXED2':dict1_list[0][1]},
              dict2 = {dict2_list[0]:'FIXED3'})
# Second Call
dframe = func(dframe, string1, str2_list[1], 
              timedelta(timedelArg_list [1]), 
              bool1 = bool1, 
              dict1 = {'FIXED1':dict1_list[1][0], 'FIXED2':dict1_list[1][1]},
              dict2 = {dict2_list[1]:'FIXED3'})
# Third Call
dframe = func(dframe, string1, str2_list[2], 
              timedelta(timedelArg_list [2]), 
              bool1 = bool1, 
              dict1 = {'FIXED1':dict1_list[2][0], 'FIXED2':dict1_list[2][1]},
              dict2 = {dict2_list[2]:'FIXED3'})
...
```

What is the most elegant way to do it.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. If you don't have control over `func`, isn't this the only way you *can* do... whatever it is you're doing?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @jonsharpe. I am thing if there is a more pythonic way as compared to the solution that I provided below. May be using `ast` library

Answer (score 1):

The brute-force way to achieve this is as follows:

```
for i in enumerate(str2_list):
   tdelta = eval('timedelta(' + timedelArg_list[i] + ')')
   dframe = func(dframe, string1, str2_list[i], 
              tdelta, 
              bool1 = bool1, 
              dict1 = {'FIXED1':dict1_list[i][0], 'FIXED2':dict1_list[i][1]},
              dict2 = {dict2_list[i]:'FIXED3'})
```